# Akka-http logging request identifier

Tags: scala, logging, akka, akka-http

I've been using **akka-http** for a while now, and so far I've mostly logged things using **scala-logging** by extending either **StrictLogging** or **LazyLogging** and then calling the:

```
log.info
log.debug
....
```

This is kinda ok, but its hard to understand which logs were generated for which request.

As solutions for this go, I've only seen:

- adding an **implicit logging context** that gets passed around (this is kinda verbose and would force me to add this context to all method calls) + custom logger that adds the context info to the logging message.
- using the **MDC** and a custom dispatcher; in order to implement this approach one would have to use the *prepare()* call which has just been deprecated.
- using **AspectJ**

Are there any other solutions that are more straightforward and less verbose ? It would be ok to change the logging library btw..

Comment: You could add a synthetic header to the request and response to carry the context through the routing tree. We are also thinking about adding request/response attributes + maybe even RequestContext attributes that would also help for that use case.

Comment: Yehp.. that's the approach in terms of inter-service communication , the issue though is propagating the value of those headers so that the service code (services, DAO, DAL,...) can also log them in their log messages ..

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would go with implicit context approach. I'd start with:

```
(path("api" / "test") & get) {
  val context = generateContext
  action(requestId)
}
```

Then I'd would make it implicit:

```
(path("api" / "test") & get) {
  implicit val context = generateContext
  action
}
```

Then I would make the context generation a directive, like e.g.:

```
val withContext: Directive1[MyContext] = Directive[Tuple1[MyContext]] {
  inner => ctx => inner(Tuple1(generateContext))(ctx)
}

withContext { implicit context =>
  (path("api" / "test") & get) {
     action
   }
}
```

Of course, you would have to take context as an implicit parameter to every action. But, it would have some advantages over MDC and AspectJ - it would be easier to test things, as you just need to pass value. Besides, who said you only ever need to pass request id and use it for logging? The context could as well pass data about logged in user, its entitlements and other things that you could resolve once, use even before calling action and reuse inside action.

As you probably guessed, this would not work if you want the ability to e.g. remove logging completely. In such case AspectJ would make more sense.

I would have most doubts with MDC. If I understand correctly it has build in assumption that all logic would happen in the same thread. If you are using `Futures` or `Tasks`, could you actually guarantee such thing? I would expect that at best all logging calls would happen in the same thread pool, but not necessarily the same thread.

Bottom line is, all possible posiltions would be some variant of what you already figured out, so the question is your exact use case.

Comment: Thanks Mateusz.. 
The implicit context is pretty much the approach I was going for , the only inconvenience is having to add the logging context as an argument to every method that wants to be able to log stuff which is kinda cumbersome.
I guess I was just hoping that there was a better, less intrusive way of doing this

Comment: Yeah, unfortunatelly it's the only reasonable way I see, if you want to access logger inside the action. If it was just a wrapper for e.g. logging request execution time, then you could do away without passing anything inside.